# Visual Studio Code forgetting my extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension for Visual Studio Code for the proprietary language that the product I code for uses because I hate the antiquated IDE ships with it. Everything is going fine except for one issue. When I close and open Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio Code seems to "forget" my extension. Syntax highlighting, code completion, commands that I've implemented all stop working. I have to disable and then enable to extension for it to start working again. I am OK with this for personal use. However, I want to push this out to other users both in and outside of the company. If any code would be helpful, let me know, and I will happily provide it.

Comment: What are your `activationEvents` in the package.json?

Comment: There pretty simple;
 "activationEvents": [
  "onCommand:iss.runIDEAScript",
  "onCommand:dialogEditor.start",
  "onCommand:dialogEditor.reload",
  "onCommand:languageBrowser"
 ],

Comment: None of the events bind to language or file extensions, so you are not developing an extension like any other. I suggest you take a look at popular language extensions out there first, and many of them are open source.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#onLanguage

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. It was because in my settings.json for VS Code I had an entry for the file extension pointing to an extension that I had removed. Removing that line from my settings.json resolved the issue of things not working when I opened VS Code.

Thanks to everybody for their comments.